# I want to update an existing record how do i do?

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE employee(
presismail varchar(50) NOT NULL,
name varchar (50),
lastname varchar (50),
CONSTRAINT presismail PRIMARY KEY (presismail))

CREATE TABLE users(
usermail varchar(50)NOT NULL,
nomail varchar (2),
CONSTRAINT usermail PRIMARY KEY (usermail))


CREATE TABLE assignment(
presismail varchar(50)NOT NULL,
usermail varchar(50)NOT NULL,
senddates varchar (20)NOT NULL,
answervalue varchar (3),
receivedates varchar (20)
CONSTRAINT PK_assignment PRIMARY KEY (presismail, usermail, senddates),
FOREIGN KEY (presismail) REFERENCES employee(presismail),
FOREIGN KEY (usermail) REFERENCES users(usermail))
```

I want to create a storedprocedure that adds values into 2 columns that has been selected.

```
insert into assignment(answervalue, receivedates)
values (@answervalue, @receivedates)
select answervalue, receivedates
from assignment
where presismail = @presismail
and usermail = @usermail
and senddates = @senddates
```

How can i do that?

Comment: you question is not clear, can you give sample records?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you want to update an existing record,

```
UPDATE assignment
SET    answervalue = @answervalue, 
       receivedates = @receivedates
WHERE  presismail = @presismail
       AND usermail = @usermail
       AND senddates = @senddates
```

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what i wanted :) Maybe i described it poorly :/

Comment: you can simply modify your question and ask that you want to update an existing record.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
insert into assignment(answervalue, receivedates) 
select answervalue, receivedates 
from assignment 
where --------
```